# A good solution to Spring MVC "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role no session or session was closed"

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

This is a well known issue of Spring MVC with Hibernate/JPA, "failed to lazily initialize a collection of role no session or session was closed". See [Hibernate: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role, no session or session was closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519059/hibernate-failed-to-lazily-initialize-a-collection-of-role-no-session-or-sessi)

Many posts suggest using `EAGER` to replace `LAZY`, which can work but has performance lost. Is there a good solution for this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This generally happens when you have your transaction management inside your DAO. The best practice is to write a service on top of the DAO and do all the gets/populations in your services. And apply transactions in services.

This way you shield your Domain models being accessed out of a database session and your services decide wether to load the children or not based on what it is supposed to do.