# when to use Lazy loading / Eager loading in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I believe there is only two ways of loading objects using Hibernate and that is lazy loading and one is eager loading. Lazy loading has its own advantages, it is not loading lots of objects but only when you need them. I also have learned that if you want to force to load all the children for an object you can simply call the `parent.getChildren().size()`. So let's say we have the following objects

```
@Entity
public class Customer{
public Set<Order> order;
}

@Entity
public class Order{
}
```

let's assume we have customers who has orders in our system and it might be more than one or even null. So my question is isn't it better to always using eager loading in this case? we need the size or some information for the order related to the customer. What is the benefit of using lazy loading in this situation, is there any benefits?

I am trying to understand where to use lazy loading and where to use eager loading, highly appreciate your insight.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I am trying to understand where to use lazy loading and where to use
>   eager loading, highly appreciate your insight.

Here are a few thoughts:

1)  If you are going to always use something (for sure), you can eager load it.
2)  Related to 1, if you are almost never going to use something, lazy load it.
3)  Lazy loading tends to be more useful when large collections are involved.
4)  Eagerly loading things will reduce session-related errors, at the potential cost of a performance hit.
5)  For complicated data models and/or large databases, you are going to see how your app does under load an adjust your strategies.
6)  It's difficult to get it right the first time.  Do what feels right, and don't be afraid to change if necessary.
7)  For large datasets, you are going to probably end up writing custom hql/queries anyway, where the default mappings can be overwritten, so lazy vs eager won't matter so much.

If you believe #6, then don't get stuck trying to plan too far ahead, and change it if you have to.

WRT your specific example, I would probably write a bunch of queries to access the data (driven by appropriate business needs, of course)

1)  A query that loads the customer, and leaves the orders in the db (so lazy loading) that I would call when I need to get customer info
2)  A query that loads the customer and all order info, for cases where I need it.  So this case I'll ignore the default mapping.

With those two queries in place, in my service layers I have the tools I need to do what is correct based on the context of the situation.

Comment: I am totally agreed,writing two separate queries are much better than using lazy/eager loading.Thanks for making it clear.

Answer (score 6):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990799/difference-between-fetchtype-lazy-and-eager-in-java-persistence) perfectly answers your question.

LAZY loading is used in cases where the related entity size is huge and it's not required to be fetched every time on the other hand

EAGER should be used with proper analysis as it loads the relationship every time the main entity is loaded.

So if a relationship is absolutely necessary for business logic computation you should think of making use of EAGER loading; LAZY loading will serve most of the cases and provides less performance trouble.