# Avoid unnecessary fetches in @onetomany join

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

I have two classes mapped to two different tables in DB.
For example ,

```
    @Entity
    @Table(schema = "schema", name = "tableA")
    public class ClassA{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "serial")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private BigInteger id;

        @Column(name="title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="middle_name")
    private String middleName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

        @Column(name ="updater")
        private BigInteger updaterId;

        @OneToOne(targetEntity=UserBean.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="updated_by",referencedColumnName="employee_number",insertable=false ,updatable=false)
    private User updatedDetails;  

 //getter setter
}
```

I have the User class as follows

```
@Entity
    @Table(schema = "schema", name = "User")
    public class User{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "serial")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private BigInteger id;

        @Column(name="title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="middle_name")
    private String middleName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    //getter setters }
```

Now when I fetch the ClassA objects through ("From ClassA"), I am getting the corresponding User class objects also. Now my question is how do I ignore the unnecessary properties of the User class.

For example, I want to ignore middleName and lastName properties of User class. I have to restrict Hibernate from reading these two columns while joining. How do I do that?

I am using Spring + Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Just change following line to Load Entity lazily

```
@OneToOne(targetEntity=UserBean.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
```

to

```
@OneToOne(targetEntity=UserBean.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
```

and read about [FetchType.EAGER VS FetchType.LAZY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990799/difference-between-fetchtype-lazy-and-eager-in-java-persistence)

If you want to Load Field of an entity Lazily you can use `@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)` annotation on fields which you want load lazily .

```
 @Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But FetchType.LAZY will fetch the entire child objects(User in this case) on demand. I want the properties of the child objects to be avoided, and only read certain properties of the child object, irrespective of FetchType.EAGER or FetchType.LAZY

Comment: How it make seance to load some field of child objects Lazily. You can not load field of an entity Lazily. only Entities can be load either Lazily or Eagerly.

Comment: That's what my exact question is. Not even lazily. I dont wanna load them at all. These properties will be needed in CRUD of the second entity. But not for me all times. Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: Some JPA providers support lazy fetching of individual elements in entities. I think it's provider specific. In general, fetch control in JPA is absolutely awful, and one of the reasons I stopped using it. See http://blog.ringerc.id.au/2012/06/mail-to-jpa-21-expert-group-re-fetch.html