# Why entity manager returns me object with null values?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, hibernate-4.x

I have spring controller, which calls service layer, and it calls Fao layer.

1) I get User object using EntityManager-s find() method. It retrieves data very well.

2) Each user have one to many relationship with School Object.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="SCHOOL_ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_USER_SHCOOL"))
    private School school;
```

3) when I get school from user entity object, hibernate logs me SQL query.

```
select school0_.id as id1_7_0_, school0_.ADDRESS as ADDRESS2_7_0_, school0_.CITY as CITY3_7_0_, 
school0_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT4_7_0_, school0_.EMAIL as EMAIL5_7_0_, school0_.NAME as NAME6_7_0_, 
school0_.version as version7_7_0_ from SCHOOL school0_ where school0_.id=2
```

when I run this query  in SQL Client, I get reall and correct data!

4) **BUT** when I get school from user entyty:

```
School s=user.getSchool()
```

It returns School object but it have all values null.

Why values are null? I'm confused. In the log, everything is well. Hibenate logs me correct query too! This query returns data, but using entity manager values are null. What can I do?

**If I change LAZY TO EAGER, EVERYTHING WORKS WELL! BUT I DO NOT LIKE THAT**
OF If I merge() existed school entity it retrieves data. I do not understand why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you define `FetchType.LAZY` fetching for  school column; take a look at `FetchType.LAZY` and `FetchType.EAGER` differences from [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990799/difference-between-fetchtype-lazy-and-eager-in-java-persistence) . If you want to get not null school object, there are 2 options:

1. Change `FetchType.LAZY`  to `FetchType.EAGER`
2. When your user object persistent call `user.getSchool()` inside `@Transaction` annotated method.