# Hibernate @MappedSuperclass @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have an abstract class AbstractDAO that all of my other DAO objects extend.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractDAO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="feed_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    @Getter @Setter private FeedDAO feed;

    @Column(name="feed_id")
    @Getter @Setter private Long feedId;
}
```

Then I have the InventoryDAO that extends this class:

```
@Entity
@Table(catalog="feed", name = "inventory")
public class InventoryDAO extends AbstractDAO {
    /**  Serial ID for this class  **/
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy="increment")
    @Column(name="id")
    @Getter @Setter private Long id;
}
```

And this is the FeedDAO:

```
@Entity
@Table(catalog="feed", name = "feed")
public class FeedDAO extends AbstractDAO {
    /**  Serial ID  **/
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy="increment")
    @Column(name="feed_id")
    @Getter @Setter private Long id;
}
```

When I query for the InventoryDAO, the feedId field is set and the feed field is null.

> InventoryDAO: {"id":1,"feed":null,"feedId":10}

However, if I query for the FeedDAO first and then for the InventoryDAO, the feed field is set.

> InventoryDAO: {"id":1,"feed":{"id":10},"feedId":10}

Now, if I change the @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY) to @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER) and query for the InventoryDAO, the feed field is always set.

> InventoryDAO: {"id":1,"feed":{"id":10},"feedId":10}

Is this a mapping issue or a limitation of the @MappedSuperclass?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990799/difference-between-fetchtype-lazy-and-eager-in-java-persistence) given here:

**

> It is not efficient to load all attributes when they are not needed.
>   So in suchlike cases, you can declare that you want entities to be
>   loaded when they are actually needed. This is called lazy loading.

**

Answer (score 0):

So after further testing, it appears that the com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.hibernate4.Hibernate4Module JSON mapper ignores lazy-loaded objects unless they are already in the session.  If I call the getFeed().getId() on the InventoryDAO object, Hibernate pulls the feed object from the database and it is included in the JSON.  When I enable the Hibernate4Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING feature for the Hibernate4Module it prints the lazy loaded objects.