# make method parameter persistent hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, state

I have the next method in DAO:

```
public List<Project> getProjects(Category category) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.merge(category);
        return category.getProjects();
    }
```

In my application **Category** is Entity. And **Project** also. **Category** has *OneToMany* relation to **Project** entity (table). Here I try to get all projects with the same category using this relation (I tried with direct SQL request - it works without problem). When I try to use this method in this way, I got exception

```
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: data.Category.project,could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

I suppose this is because inside method **Category** is in detached state and I try to make in managed again but with merge command without success((( Or I am wrong. Is it possible to use such code? Not use direct SQL command.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem would be because the objects are being loaded with `fetch = FetchType.LAZY strategy`. You may wanna learn about [what is Eager fetch and what is Lazy fetch.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990799/difference-between-fetchtype-lazy-and-eager-in-java-persistence)

Basically

> LAZY = fetch when needed
>
> EAGER = fetch immediately

**Solution 1 (Recommended): Use Eager Fetch strategy in your Category Class:**

```
public class Category {
    ...
    ...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Projects> projects;
    ...
    ...
    
    //Getters and Setters
    
    /* P.S. - I don't know what's the actual code for your classes. 
    I just assumed it to be somewhat like this. Please post your code if you face 
    any further problem and I'll modify my answer accordingly. */
}
```

Your DAO would look somewhat like this:

```
public List<Project> getProjects(Category category) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.merge(category);
        List<Project> projects = category.getProjects();
        session.close()
        return projects;
}
```

**Solution 2: Send Session object along with your category class**

This way you would ensure that session isn't closed when you actually need it to access your objects

```
public void yourMethod() {
    //Declare Session in starting of your class where you're accessing the objects
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Category category = new Category();
    ...
    ...
    List <Project> projects = getProjects(category, session);
    ...
    ...
    //Perform all of your operations here
    ...
    ...
    session.close(); //Close session at the end 
}
```

DAO method

```
public List<Project> getProjects(Category category, Session session) {
    session.merge(category);
    return category.getProjects();
}
```