# Spring Data REST: NULL values issue

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have an implementation with Spring Data REST for a Person class and a Contract class.

This is my **Person.class**:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Person {

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String surname;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Contract> contracts;

}
```

This is my **Contract.class**:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Contract {

    @Column
    private String contractType;

    @Column
    private String contractDesc;

}
```

These are my **tables definitions and data** (script auto-generated in an embedded HSQL DataBase):

```
CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.PERSON(ID, NAME, SURNAME, CONTRACT_ID);
CREATE MEMORY TABLE PUBLIC.CONTRACT(ID, CONTRACTTYPE, CONTRACTDESC);
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.PERSON ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY FOREIGN KEY(CONTRACT_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.CONTRACT(ID);
INSERT INTO PERSON VALUES('9876543210abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv', 'Jack', 'Reds','1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv');
INSERT INTO CONTRACT VALUES('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv', 'OTHER', 'Other');
```

This is the **response obtained** from Spring Data REST, at my url:
localhost/my-app/api/persons/

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "persons" : [ {
      "name" : "Jack",
      "surname" : "Reds",
      "contract" : {
        "contractType" : "OTHER",
        "contractDesc" : "Other",
    ...
```

But if I execute this portion of code:

```
List<Person> persons = personRepository.findAll(new PersonSpec("TEST"));
```

in debug the variable "persons" is valorized with this data:

```
persons= ArrayList<E> (id=233)
    elementData=Object[7] (id=235)
        [0]= Person (id=236)
            name= "Jack" (id=176)
            surname= "Reds" (id=180)
            contract= Contract_$$_jvst951_d (id=240)
                contractType= null
                contractDesc= null
        [1]= Person (id=237)
        [2]= Person (id=238)
    modCount=1
    size = 3
```

"contractType" and "contractDesc" are setted to NULL.
Furthermore, my PersonSpec seems to don't make any filtering with these fields:

```
public class PersonSpec implements Specification<Person> {

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Person> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) {

            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(searchParam.getContract())) {
                predicates.add(cb.and(cb.and(cb.isNotNull(root.get("contract")),
                                             cb.isNotNull(root.get("contract").get("contractType"))),
                                       cb.equal(root.get("contract").get("contractType"), searchParam.getContract())));
            }
```

What's wrong? I don't understand why there is no link between my Person and my Contract.

Thanks.

Comment: There is a discrepancy between your datamodel and your mapping. According to the datamodel, a `Person` has one `Contract` (because table `PERSON` has a column `CONTRACT_ID`) but according to the mapping, a `Person` has a `List<Contract>`.

Comment: I converted into:  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Contract contract;  but I still have the problem.

Comment: also try to replace the predicate with this : `predicates.add(cb.equal(root.join("contract").get("contractType"), searchParam.getContract()))`

Comment: And remove `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` on the relationship.

Comment: if i remove fetch = FetchType.LAZY it gives me the error: org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens because of the LAZY loading - when you do the `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` it doesn't take care of bringing the `Contract` data, hence why it displays as `null`.

You can try by changing the `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` to `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` or instantiate the object yourself.

Here's some extra info on LAZY vs EAGER:

- [Difference between FetchType LAZY and EAGER in Java persistence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990799/difference-between-fetchtype-lazy-and-eager-in-java-persistence)
- [Hibernate Eager vs Lazy Fetch Type](https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/hibernate-eager-vs-lazy-fetch-type/)

**UPDATE** 
I know it has been a while, but another way that you can fetch a lazy collection it's by doing on your service something like:

```
persons.contracts.size();
```

Just make sure that your method includes the `@Transactional` annotation