# Spring/hibernate/MySQL doesnt save in auxiliar table states

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, many-to-many

I have 3 tables Users, Archivements and ArchivemetnsUSers. This is a relathionship Many-To-Many.

My problem is that i want save a new user in my DataBase but, i dont want save/update the archivement assigned to user, because i have only N pre-existent archivements.

Then, when i go to save hibernate session for my user... i get a exception: the selected archivement exists in DataBase, and hibernate cant save duplicate PrimaryKey.

How i avoid this problem?

Any annotation? or trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, the problem was that i need get archivements, set archivements  to user and save user instance in ONE TRANSACTION, for hibernate understand that these archivements registers exist in DataBase.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid this problem you will have to fetch the Archivement from database and assign it to the new user you have created, for Ex :

```
//fetching the Archivement:
Archivements a=yourDaoClass.getArchivementById(id);

//creating a new user
Users u=new Users();
u.setName("someOne");

//assign the new user to the existing ashivement
List<User> users=a.getUsers();
users.add(u);
a.setUsers(users);
session.saveOrUpdate(a);
```

this must assign the existing Achivement to the new User.

Comment: Ty for answer but i test it and doest work.
Same behaviour. Save method try save Archivements too.. And return a conflict  Duplicate Primary key.

Comment: int your user class u have declared a list of achivements right ??

Comment: in user clase i have a @OneToMany(mappedBy="user",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Archivements> archivements = new HashSet<Archivements>();

The ManyToMany works fine.. but i dont want that save archivements in DataBase, only.

If i dont put Cascade.ALL then ArchivemetnsUSers doesnt persist

Comment: i get other problems: nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.MyProject.pojo.Archivements.ArchivementsUser, could not initialize proxy - no Session

On other hand, i think that isnt good idea save for Archivements, because y have other relationships with User ManyToMany, that i need create in the future...

Comment: on your Users Class make the list of achivements with fetch type **EAGER**

Comment: ty for help but this havent sense. EAGER is default type of fetch, and your funtion is clear in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990799/difference-between-fetchtype-lazy-and-eager-in-java-persistence.