# Hibernate, lazy behaviour and multiple sessions

Tags: java, hibernate

Suppose I have a `Post` class which has a `PostComment` collection, and that I load Post. PostComment has lazy="true" set, so PostComment is now represented by an Hibernate Proxy.

If I load `Post` in a session, let's call it `session1`, and then I close session1 before accessing PostComment, how can I access PostComment from a second session opened later?

I tried to access PostComment from session2 but got LazyInizializationException, I believed that to enable lazy loading it was enough to have a session opened, not the same session which loaded the parent object.

Should I use session2.update() to attach the objects to session2? Are there other methods other than using the same session in the whole process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either reattach the object to a new session as you've described in your post or instead disable lazy initialization by using `FetchType.EAGER` as your fetch type i.e.:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Map<String, Attribute> attributes = new HashMap<String, Attribute>();
```

See this post for more info about the differences between lazy and eager fetching: [Difference between FetchType LAZY and EAGER in Java Persistence API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990799/difference-between-fetchtype-lazy-and-eager-in-java-persistence-api)