# Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am workin with Spring Boot 1.5.10, Spring Data JPA and Hibernate.

When I search by Id the entity Person the result is correct, but when I try to build a query with a List my request return a exception:

```
Failed to write HTTP message: 
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: 
Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: us.icitap.entities.tims.Person.otherNames, could not initialize proxy - no Session; 
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: us.icitap.entities.tims.Person.otherNames, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->us.icitap.entities.tims.Person["otherNames"])
```

The code of the entity I am working on:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PERSON", schema = "TIMS")
@NamedQuery(name="Person.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Person p")
public class Person extends PersonAbstract {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to PersonOtherName
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="person")
    private List<PersonOtherName> otherNames;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Photo
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="person")
    private List<Photo> photos;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to TravelDocument
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="person")
    private List<TravelDocument> travelDocuments;

    public Person() {
    }

    public List<PersonOtherName> getOtherNames() {
        return this.otherNames;
    }

    public void setOtherNames(List<PersonOtherName> otherNames) {
        this.otherNames = otherNames;
    }

    public PersonOtherName addOtherName(PersonOtherName otherName) {
        getOtherNames().add(otherName);
        otherName.setPerson(this);
        return otherName;
    }

    public PersonOtherName removeOtherName(PersonOtherName otherName) {
        getOtherNames().remove(otherName);
        otherName.setPerson(null);
        return otherName;
    }

    public List<Photo> getPhotos() {
        return this.photos;
    }

    public void setPhotos(List<Photo> photos) {
        this.photos = photos;
    }

    public Photo addPhoto(Photo photo) {
        getPhotos().add(photo);
        photo.setPerson(this);
        return photo;
    }

    public Photo removePhoto(Photo photo) {
        getPhotos().remove(photo);
        photo.setPerson(null);
        return photo;
    }

    public List<TravelDocument> getTravelDocuments() {
        return this.travelDocuments;
    }

    public void setTravelDocuments(List<TravelDocument> travelDocuments) {
        this.travelDocuments = travelDocuments;
    }

    public TravelDocument addTravelDocument(TravelDocument travelDocument) {
        getTravelDocuments().add(travelDocument);
        travelDocument.setPerson(this);
        return travelDocument;
    }

    public TravelDocument removeTravelDocument(TravelDocument travelDocument) {
        getTravelDocuments().remove(travelDocument);
        travelDocument.setPerson(null);
        return travelDocument;
    }
}
```

The relevant part of the service:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<Person> searchByExpression(List<Criterion> expressions) {
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    List<Person> persons = null;
    try {
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
        for (Criterion simpleExpression : expressions) {
            criteria.add(simpleExpression);
        }
        persons = criteria.list();                      
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }
    session.close();
    return persons;
}

@Override
public Person searchPersonById(Long id) {       
    return personRepository.findOne(id);
}
```

The controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/tims/person")
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/searchPersonById/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Person> searchById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        try {
            Person person = this.personService.searchPersonById(id);
            if (person == null)
                return new ResponseEntity<Person>(null, null, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            else 
                return new ResponseEntity<Person>(person, null, HttpStatus.OK);
        }catch(Exception e){
            HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            httpHeaders.set("Exception", e.getMessage());
            ResponseEntity<Person> respond = new ResponseEntity<Person>(null, httpHeaders, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            return respond;
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping("/searchPersonByGenerality")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Person>> searchPersonByGenerality(String pid, String name, String surname, GenderEnum gender, String dateOfBirth){
        List<Person> persons = null;
        Date date = null;
        try {
            if(dateOfBirth != null) {
                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
                date = df.parse(dateOfBirth);
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            if (pid != null && !pid.isEmpty()) {
                persons = this.personService.searchPersons(pid, name, surname, gender, date);
                return new ResponseEntity<List<Person>>(persons, null, HttpStatus.OK);
            }
            int valid = 0;
            List<Criterion> expressions = new ArrayList<>();
            if(name != null & !name.isEmpty()) {
                name = name.toUpperCase();
                valid = valid + 5;
                if (name.contains("%") || name.contains("_")) {                 
                    expressions.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("translate({alias}.name, 'ËÇ', 'EC') like '" + MyString.transformAccentsLetter(name) + "'"));
                }else 
                    expressions.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("translate({alias}.name, 'ËÇ', 'EC') = '" + MyString.transformAccentsLetter(name) + "'"));
            }
            if(surname != null & !surname.isEmpty()) {
                surname = surname.toUpperCase();
                valid = valid + 5;
                if (surname.contains("%") || surname.contains("_")) {
                    expressions.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("translate({alias}.surname, 'ËÇ', 'EC') like '" + MyString.transformAccentsLetter(surname) + "'"));
                }else 
                    expressions.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("translate({alias}.surname, 'ËÇ', 'EC') = '" + MyString.transformAccentsLetter(surname) + "'"));
            }
            if (gender != null) {
                valid = valid + 2;
                expressions.add(Restrictions.eq("gender", gender));
            }
            if (date != null) {
                valid = valid + 3;
                expressions.add(Restrictions.between("dateOfBirth", atStartOfDay(date), atEndOfDay(date)));
            }
            persons = personService.searchByExpression(expressions);
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Person>>(persons, null, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            httpHeaders.set("Exception", e.getMessage());
            ResponseEntity<List<Person>> respond = new ResponseEntity<List<Person>>(null, httpHeaders,
                    HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            return respond;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me find what's going wrong in my code?

Comment: Your methods are way to crowded. There is too much going on to understand and spot errors for sure. Try to break down your code in smaller methods.

Comment: Did you find the solution? Do you need any more help with this? If any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 3):

That is the default strategy to retrieve data from the database in a `@OneToMany` relationship, data should be fetched lazily when it is first accessed, and in this case, you are trying to serialize the entity after closing the session. Try to establish an `EAGER` fetch strategy for this property (take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2990799/4071001) for details):

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="person")
private List<PersonOtherName> otherNames;
```

Alternatively, you can force the proxy initialization for this specific service before closing the session:

```
Hibernate.initialize(person.getOtherNames());
```

---

> If you don't need to show this data in the interface, a more efficient
>   solution would be not even serialize them:

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy="person")
private List<PersonOtherName> otherNames;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out your exception, it says: `could not initialize proxy - no Session`. That means that your session is not properly intialized.

Try to debug your app and see what happens when you run

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
```