# Hibernate :HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

Tags: java, json, hibernate, restful-url

below is my hibernate code:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        Session session = null;
        LoginEntity user = null;

        try {

            sessionFactory = HibernateUtility.getSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            user = session.get(LoginEntity.class, user_id);

            System.out.println(user.getUserCountryMapping()); // if I remove this line I get error..

            session.getTransaction().commit();
            return user;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(BulkActionMethods.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        } finally {
            if (session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
```

I am facing a weird issue with my code, When I remove the `System.out.println(user.getUserCountryMapping());` line I am getting `HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error` error on browser but when I write this line I am getting expacted `JSON` response on browser..
Please someone help me to understand this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

`System.out.println(user.getUserCountryMapping());`

with

`Hibernate.initialize(user.getUserCountryMapping());`

Read more about [lazy vs eager fetch type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990799/difference-between-fetchtype-lazy-and-eager-in-java-persistence-api).

Comment: Thanks Kartik It Worked for me. :)

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing the error or your entity mappings, it's hard to give a firm answer.

However, cases like this are almost always due to uninitialized lazy collections.  The line:

```
System.out.println(user.getUserCountryMapping());
```

makes `Hibernate` fetch the data in that relationship.  If you don't do this within a `Hibernate` session, and then try to rely on this relationship later you will get a `LazyInitializationException`, if not handled it will be a HTTP status 500.