# Spring Data JPA : Repository DeleteById method not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an issue which I do not understand with my Spring Data JPA Repository. I have the following entity :

```java
@Entity
public class Ability {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String color;
    private String image;

    @ManyToOne(
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    private Subject subject;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "ability",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER
    )
    private Set<Technology> technologies;
```

And a JPA Repository for this entity.
What I dot not understand, is that when I use the `deleteById` method of my Jpa Repository, the record is not deleted from the database. Strange thing is that it works fine in my integration test using an InMemory database.
It works if I override the `deleteById` with the following :

```java
    @Modifying
    @Query("DELETE FROM Ability a WHERE a.id = :id")
    void deleteById(@Param("id") Integer id);
```

But I suspect I shouldn't have to do that. Any clue with the method does not work as expected ?

EDIT : Add endpoint source code

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/subjects/{subjectId}/abilities")
public class AbilityController {
    ...
    
    private final AbilityRepository abilityRepository;
    private final TechnologyRepository technologyRepository;
    private final SubjectRepository subjectRepository;

    public AbilityController(AbilityRepository abilityRepository, TechnologyRepository technologyRepository, SubjectRepository subjectRepository) {
        this.abilityRepository = abilityRepository;
        this.technologyRepository = technologyRepository;
        this.subjectRepository = subjectRepository;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("{abilityId}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void deleteAbility(@PathVariable("subjectId") Integer subjectId, @PathVariable("abilityId") Integer abilityId) {
        if (!abilityRepository.existsAbilityBySubjectId(subjectId, abilityId)) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException(String.format("No ability with Id : %s", abilityId));
        }

        abilityRepository.deleteById(abilityId);
    }
    ...
}
```

EDIT : Add Hibernate SQL

```sql
Hibernate: 
    select
        ability0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        ability0_.color as color2_0_0_,
        ability0_.image as image3_0_0_,
        ability0_.name as name4_0_0_,
        ability0_.subject_id as subject_5_0_0_,
        subject1_.id as id1_7_1_,
        subject1_.icon as icon2_7_1_,
        subject1_.image as image3_7_1_,
        subject1_.name as name4_7_1_,
        technologi2_.ability_id as ability_4_8_2_,
        technologi2_.id as id1_8_2_,
        technologi2_.id as id1_8_3_,
        technologi2_.ability_id as ability_4_8_3_,
        technologi2_.image as image2_8_3_,
        technologi2_.name as name3_8_3_ 
    from
        ability ability0_ 
    left outer join
        subject subject1_ 
            on ability0_.subject_id=subject1_.id 
    left outer join
        technology technologi2_ 
            on ability0_.id=technologi2_.ability_id 
    where
        ability0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        abilities0_.subject_id as subject_5_0_0_,
        abilities0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        abilities0_.id as id1_0_1_,
        abilities0_.color as color2_0_1_,
        abilities0_.image as image3_0_1_,
        abilities0_.name as name4_0_1_,
        abilities0_.subject_id as subject_5_0_1_ 
    from
        ability abilities0_ 
    where
        abilities0_.subject_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        technologi0_.ability_id as ability_4_8_0_,
        technologi0_.id as id1_8_0_,
        technologi0_.id as id1_8_1_,
        technologi0_.ability_id as ability_4_8_1_,
        technologi0_.image as image2_8_1_,
        technologi0_.name as name3_8_1_ 
    from
        technology technologi0_ 
    where
        technologi0_.ability_id=?
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, just to make sure: you run your production code, wait for the transaction to commit, then check to see that the entity was not deleted from the data store?

Comment: Maybe some foreign key constraint fails and it does not complete. Check the logs of your application

Comment: @crizzis Yes exactly. I assume that when the HTTP request is resolved, the transaction has been committed.

Comment: @Boug I have no error in my logs. In fact I log Hibernate's SQL and no "DELETE" command is executed

Comment: then post your service and your controller. somehow it malfunctions there

Comment: @Boug Just added the endpoint source code

Comment: where is that delcared in your path `@PathVariable("subjectId") Integer subjectId` ?

Comment: you have only `DeleteMapping("{abilityId}")`

Comment: Yes it in the controller Path, just edited it in

Comment: can you check with a System.out.println does it come with the right parameters just before deleteById() is called?

Comment: I just did, they are correct and correspond to what I have in the database

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The "problem" is your mapping. Your collection is retrieved eagerly. Now why would that be an issue? The `deleteById` in Spring Data JPA first does a findById which in your case, loads the associated entities eagerly.

Now entity is attempting to be deleted but due to it being still attached and referenced by another entity it would be persisted again, hence the delete is canceled.

Possible solutions:

- Delete using a query and write your own query method for this
- Mark either side of the association lazy

Example:

```
@Entity
public class Ability {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String color;
    private String image;

    @ManyToOne(
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private Subject subject;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "ability",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private Set<Technology> technologies;
}

@Repository
public interface AbilityRepository extends CrudRepository<Ability, Integer> {
}
```

Controller:

```
abilityRepository.deleteById(abilityId);
```

Comment: Yes I already avec a JpaRepository for my entity. And that's when I use the existing `deleteById` that the deletion is not persisted to the database.

Comment: Do you have some exception ?

Comment: No I don't have any exception

Comment: @Ombrelin then consider that your datasource points to a different database ;)

Comment: Can you also try to add abilityRepository.flush() after abilityRepository.deleteById(abilityId); ?

Comment: @AkifHadziabdic The behaviour is exactly the same when adding a `flush()`

Comment: Can you save one new item in order to confirm you are checking the correct data source (database)?

Comment: @Boug I really don't think so since I double checked my credentials and when I replace the `deleteById` method as said in the post, the deletion is persisted to the database.

Comment: @AkifHadziabdic, yes I just did and inserting a new item works as intended

Comment: Can you enable hibernate SQL logging in order to check is query sent to database? spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231283/discussion-between-akif-hadziabdic-and-ombrelin).

Comment: Thank you for you detailed answer, I understand the problem thanks to you and the fix worked indeed.

Comment: I can confirm that using `FetchType.LAZY` resolves a similar problem in my case.

Comment: It solved my problem also -by using FetchType.LAZY. Thanks