# My repository is not called in my service - Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, repository

I don't understand why my weight record Repository is not called in spite of my code. I have written some logs before and after the weight record repository call. In my console, I can see that logs are called before and after, but not my repository. I have a code 200 OK, but in my database, my data is always here. I don't understand why. My Tomcat port is set to port 7777. I can create and read data but not delete it.

Just below my code : ENTITY, CONTROLLER, REPOSITORY and SERVICE.

https://gitlab.com/genetquentin/openweighttracker_backend/-/tree/develop

```
/*ENTITY 'PERSON'*/
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_person")
    private Long idPerson;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_initial_data")
    private InitialData userInitData;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_user")
    private AppUser appUserPerson;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "person")
    private List<WeightRecord> weightsList = new ArrayList<WeightRecord>();
    
    /* Getters and setters */



      /*ENTITY 'WEIGHTRECORD'*/

        @Entity
        @Table(name = "weight_record")
        public class WeightRecord implements Serializable{
        
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            @Column(name = "id_weight_record")
            private Long idWeightRecord;
            
            @Column(name = "weight_record_date", nullable = true)
            private LocalDate weightRecordDate;
        
            //JsonIgnore annotation because circular problem with Jackson and entity.
            @JsonIgnore
            @ManyToOne
            private Person person;
            
            @Min(1)
            @Max(635)
            @Column(name = "weight_kg_record", nullable = true, precision = 1)
            private Double weightKgRecord;
        
            @Min(1)
            @Max(99)
            @Column(name = "percent_fat_mass", nullable = true, precision = 1)
            private Double percentFatMass;
        
            @Min(1)
            @Max(99)
            @Column(name = "percent_muscular_mass", nullable = true, precision = 1)
            private Double percentMuscularMass;
        
            @Min(1)
            @Max(99)
            @Column(name = "percent_body_water", nullable = true, precision = 1)
            private Double percentBodyWater;
        
            @Min(1)
            @Max(99)
            @Column(name = "percent_bone_mass", nullable = true, precision = 1)
            private Double percentBoneMass
        
            /* Getters and setters */
        
    
    
            /*CONTROLLER*/    
                @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
                @RestController
                @RequestMapping("/weights")
                public class WeightRecordController {
                
                    @Autowired
                    WeightRecordServiceImpl weightRecordServiceImpl;
                
                    @Autowired
                    WeightRecordRepository weightRecordRepository;
                
                    @Autowired
                    AppUserRepository appUserRepository;
                
                    @Autowired
                    PersonRepository personRepository;
                
                    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WeightRecordController.class);
                
                    
                    //TODO : Weight is not deleted  and repository not called ?
                    // USE deleteinbatch method repository from jpa ?
                    @DeleteMapping("/{weightId}")
                    public ResponseEntity<WeightRecord> deleteWeigthById(@PathVariable("weightId") Long weightId, Principal principal) {
                        logger.info("DELETE /weights/{}", weightId);
                        try {
                            
                            Long appUserConnectedId = this.getAppUserConnectedId(principal);
                            Person personConnected = personRepository.findById(appUserConnectedId).orElseThrow();
                            WeightRecord weightRecordToDelete = weightRecordRepository.findById(weightId).orElseThrow();
                            
                            if(personConnected != null && personConnected.getWeightsList().contains(weightRecordToDelete)) {
                                logger.info("SERVICE FOR DELETING");
                                logger.info(weightRecordToDelete.getWeightKgRecord().toString());
                                return ResponseEntity.ok(weightRecordServiceImpl.deleteWeightById(weightId));
                            } else {
                                logger.info("BAD USER FOR BAD WEIGHT");
                                return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
                            }
                        } catch (NoSuchElementException nse) {
                            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
                        }   
                    }
                }
            
    
    
    /*REPOSITORY*/
    
            
                @Repository
                public interface WeightRecordRepository extends JpaRepository<WeightRecord, Long> {
                }
            
            
    
    
    /*SERVICE*/
            
            @Service
            public class WeightRecordServiceImpl implements WeightRecordService {
            
                @Autowired
                WeightRecordRepository weightRecordRepository;
            
                @Autowired
                AppUserRepository appUserRepository;
            
                @Autowired
                PersonRepository personRepository;
            
                private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WeightRecordServiceImpl.class);
            
                public WeightRecord deleteWeightById(Long weightRecordToDeleteId) {
                    
                    logger.info("THIS IS THE WEIGHT ID TO DELETE : {}", weightRecordToDeleteId);
                    WeightRecord weightRecordToDelete = weightRecordRepository.findById(weightRecordToDeleteId).orElseThrow();
                    weightRecordRepository.deleteById(weightRecordToDeleteId);
                    logger.info("Weight with id n°{} is deleted now", weightRecordToDelete.getIdWeightRecord());
                    return weightRecordToDelete;
                }
```

My request in Insomnia:
[image: My request in Insomnia]

Result of request in console:
[image: Result of request in console]

Comment: Please read [why you should not post images of code, logs, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Do you happen to have bidirectional relationship between `Person` and `WeightRecord`? Your comment on person field makes me believe so. If this is indeed the case, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67150443/spring-data-jpa-repository-deletebyid-method-not-working), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688402/delete-not-working-with-jparepository) as well, should explain the cause of the issue and how to fix.

Comment: Yes i have a bidirectionnel relationship with Person ans WeightRecord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The reason**

The reason of the issue is this part of the code

```java
personConnected.getWeightsList().contains(weightRecordToDelete)
```

**Why it happens?**

There is a spring data property `spring.jpa.open-in-view` and it is `true` by default. It means that JPA Persistent Context (Hibernate Session) is opened during entire HTTP request. [What is this spring.jpa.open-in-view=true property in Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48222934/3405171)

If Persistent Context is opened, `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` property in the code below doesn't work at all.

```java
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "person")
private List<WeightRecord> weightsList = new ArrayList<WeightRecord>();
```

When you do `personConnected.getWeightsList().conatins()`, Hibernate loads `weightsList` in the background. That's why the last SQL log entry is logged.

```
    select
        weightslis0_.person_id_person as person_i8_3_0_
    ...
    from
        weight_record weightslis0_ 
    where
        weightslis0_.person_id_person=?
```

So when you delete a `WeightRecord`, it remains in the `Person.weightsList`, because of it was loaded by `personConnected.getWeightsList().conatins()`.

When HTTP request is completed, Persistent Context becomes closed, and Hibernate flushes all changes to the database. There is `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` on the `Person` side, so Hibernate should keep in mind a deleted `WeightRecord` in the `weightsList`. So it does nothing, because you could delete `WeightRecord` and insert it by some reasons again.

You can verify statements above just by removing `personConnected.getWeightsList().conatins()` part of the code, delete will start work.

**How to solve**

1. Set `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` in the `application.property`. So you will have `LazyInitializationException` with `personConnected.getWeightsList().conatins()`
2. Remove `personConnected.getWeightsList().conatins()` code. You can do the same just comparing `WeightRecord.Person.id` and a current `Person.id`.

```java
        Optional<Person> personConnected = personRepository.findById(appUserConnectedId);
        if (personConnected.isPresent()  ) {
            WeightRecord weightRecordToDelete = weightRecordRepository.findById(weightId).orElseThrow();
            Long userPersonId = personConnected.get().getIdPerson();
            Long recordPersonId = weightRecordToDelete.getPerson().getIdPerson();
            if (Objects.equals(userPersonId, recordPersonId)) {
                logger.info("SERVICE FOR DELETING");
                return ResponseEntity.ok(weightRecordServiceImpl.deleteWeightById(weightRecordToDelete));
            }
        }

        logger.info("BAD USER FOR BAD WEIGHT");
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
```

Now you can keep `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` on the `weightsList` on `Person` side.

**Notes**

Always use `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false`. `LazyInitializationException` is your friend.

Always use `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` on the `@ManyToOne` part of the association. It is `FetchType.EAGER` by default.

```java
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Person person;
```

Never use Jackson annotations like `@JsonIgnore` and Hibernate Validator annotations like `@Min(1)` with entities.
Use `PersonEntity` class for an entity and `Person` for JSON. Do mapping on the service level.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, i have juste deleted the CascadeType.ALL from my @OneToMany entity Person and all is working. I can create, read and delete records from database. 
But I'am going to investigate more this problem to understand in a better way its origin.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "person")
    public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_person")
    private Long idPerson;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_initial_data")
    private InitialData userInitData;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_user")
    private AppUser appUserPerson;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "person")
    private List<WeightRecord> weightsList = new ArrayList<WeightRecord>();
```

Comment: That's interesting. But you will not be able to do anything with `weightsList` from a `Person` side. For example, `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` doesn't allow delete happens too. For `Person` it is okay, because we don't need to create a `Person` with filled weights list.

Comment: Thanks for help and feedback, for the moment i have not found another solution... To be continued ;-)

Comment: I have found explanation. See my answer please.