Delete not executing in spring data jpa
i am facing an issue when trying to delete the Cart entity in my application using Hibernate. When I attempt to delete it, Hibernate doesn't even execute the SQL to perform the deletion in the database.
I've already tried creating simple delete methods without any additional logic, just the delete operation, but even then, nothing happens.
  @PostMapping("/webhook")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> test(@RequestBody String payload, @RequestHeader("Stripe-Signature") String sigHeader) {
        cartService.cartWebHook(payload, sigHeader);
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }

package com.gustavolyra.e_commerce_api.entities;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_cart")
public class Cart {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", unique = true)
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<CartItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Cart cart = (Cart) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, cart.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(id);
    }
}


    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void cartWebHook(String payload, String header) {
        try {
            Event event = Webhook.constructEvent(payload, header, stripeWebhookSecret);

            if ("checkout.session.completed".equals(event.getType())) {
                var cartId = findCartIdFromWebHook(event);
                if (cartId != null) {
                    var cart = cartRepository.findById(Long.valueOf(cartId));
                    cart.ifPresent(value -> cartRepository.deleteById(value.getId()));
                }
            }
        } catch (SignatureVerificationException e) {
            throw new WebHookException(e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


have you tried debuggin it? could it be that cartId is null, and therefore deleteById doesn't get called?

Try using FetchType.LAZY.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67150443/spring-data-jpa-repository-deletebyid-method-not-working

Some tips: findById is completely unnecessary here. You may pass your Id to deleteById directly. Non existing entries will be silently ignored. If you occasionally want to check for the existence of an entity with a specific Id you'd better use existsById. This will you give you the information you want without fetching the entity completely.
